# Select area at image with jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, selection, rounding

i know how to select area of image, with jQuery plugin ofcause.
Here is http://publikz.com/one-more-task-rounded-selection-in-jquery/ shot example 
(click link "Here is example").

But want also - to know how to make round selection, i.e. wysiwig selection. How to make round thumbnail - this is just another php task, nothing more.

Can anybody help me with ideas?face

Comment: So you want the selection area to be round, not rectangular? Also you say "this is just another php task, nothing more" -- yet your title you have jQuery and don't even have PHP tagged. Can you clarify

Comment: I need select round. After i select, will proceed it. I.e. - i wselect round from image, than clicks something and make somehting from image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is example. Drag the yellow pointer ... 
http://publikz.com/projects/roundsel-v2/